# Как обратиться к элементам (0 индекса) вложенного массива внутри объекта js?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

```
 let object = {
    'uno': [1, 2, 23],
    'one': [3, 4, 5],
    'mess': [6, 7, 8],
    'ivan': [9, 10]
}
```

Нужно обратиться к вложенным массивам внутри объекта и вывести нулевые по индексу элементы т.е. 1,3,6,9

Comment: цикл...........вы умеете?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let obj = {
  'uno': [1, 2, 23],
  'one': [3, 4, 5],
  'mess': [6, 7, 8],
  'ivan': [9, 10]
}
for (let p in obj) {
  console.log(p, obj[p][0]);
}
```

Comment: мда,как элементрарно..а я в своей голове всё усложнила.Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

```
const values = Object.values(object).map(a => a[0]);

console.log(values);
```